# Change the theme of my whole android studio application confusion

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-theme

I just starting learning android and I want to change the theme of my whole android application. [Based on this](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

I want to change the theme to the Dark Material theme. In my androidmanifest.xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Material"> // here is the change
```

But my application cannot recognize the Theme.Material this theme? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `android:theme="@style/Theme.Material">` to:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material">
```

Comment: And he says api level at least 21, any other methods?

Comment: the theme that you want to use is for API level 21, if you targeted lower APIs you should use different theme

Comment: but i check my project structure and my api is 26

Comment: check your minimum API maybe it is set to 10 or 15 it is in your build.gradle file

Comment: i change the minisdkversion from 15 to 21 and use your code above, when i compile, the theme does not change

Comment: In your manifest beside application theme, there is also an activity theme (nested inside application tag), make sure you also change that

Comment: when I change the application theme and one of my activity theme, when i click the button related to that theme changed activity, the program crashed, should i change all of the activities' themes?

Comment: Does your application do fine with the default theme and without the Theme.Material?

Comment: In the end, I use the Theme.Appcombat which is similar to the Theme.material thanks though